# Ubuntu 14.04 disable secondary desktop in Unity

Tags: multiple-monitors, multiple-desktops

Is there a way to disable Unity from creating a secondary desktop if I have two monitors plugged in?

My secondary monitor is actually a receiver for sound, so there is no need to have a desktop assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else out there has this same problem try this answer from Antoniu Mesesan [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101490/mirror-dual-monitors-with-different-resolutions):

`xrandr --output NAME-OF-DISPLAY1 --rate 60 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 1920x1080 --panning 1920x1080* --output NAME-OF-DISPLAY2 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as NAME-OF-DISPLAY1`

you can get the names of the display and supported output resolutions by simply using the `xrandr` command

What this does is stacks your desktops on top of eachother so that it appears & behaves as though there is only one desktop. I am sure thre are going to be some glitches (one already is that the Unity System gear launcher menu is displaying off the screen), but it may be worth the work if you need this solution.

Comment: Im still open to a real solution, as opposed to this workaround.